# How to fix MySQL 8 error codes : 1525 and 1292?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, mysql-8.0

**For invalid dates** on Mysql 8 server, I'm getting 2 types of errors :-

1. *Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATE value: '2019-09-31'.*
2. *Warning Code : 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2019-09-31 23:59:59' for column 'date_column' at row 1 .*

**Can anyone please suggest how to resolve / fix / ignore these errors for invalid dates on mysql 8?**

We're migrating our database servers from **MySQL 5 to MySQL 8**. I'm running the following 2 queries on both the servers :-

Query 1 : `SELECT * FROM db1.table1 WHERE date_column >= '2019-09-01 00:00:00' AND date_column <= '2019-09-31 23:59:59' ;`

Query 2 : `SELECT * FROM db1.table1 WHERE date_column BETWEEN '2019-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-09-31 23:59:59' ;`

**On mysql 5 server**, I'm getting no error / warning and both the queries return same results.

**On mysql 8 server**, Query 1 breaks with error code 1525 while Query 2 runs successfully with no result (though there are results) with warning code 1292 and message "Incorrect datetime value: ''2019-09-31 23:59:59'' for column 'date_column' at row 1" .

Comment: September has only 31 days.  Refer to a valid day and you'll be fine.  For instance `'2019-09-30'` or `'2019-10-01'`.

Comment: You can misconfigure the 8.x server to accept invalid dates but it's likely to come back later and bite you. Is there a chance to just fix the invalid records?

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but I want resolution for invalid dates only .

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I tried configuring mysql 8 server using "ALLOW_INVALID_DATES" but query returns no results in that case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, "_September has only 31 days_"?!?

Comment: @Álvaro González As we're migrating from MySQL 5 to MySQL 8, fixing the invalid date queries would require a lot of effort in code change. Hence I'm looking for a solution which requires least changes like changes in configuration only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lesser evil is possibly to change the session-wide SQL mode for both the migration script and the affected application—that should be a simple one time change (as long as the connection code is not copy+pasted in a hundred places). The mode that allows invalid dates is [ALLOW_INVALID_DATES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates):

```
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',', @@SESSION.sql_mode, 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES');
```

Full [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f48ec79ab2e127a795942b1c2dc25cab):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo (bar DATE);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode                         |
+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('2019-02-30');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '2019-02-30' for column 'bar' at row 1
mysql> SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',', @@SESSION.sql_mode, 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES');
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('2019-02-30');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+------------+
| bar        |
+------------+
| 2019-02-30 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks @Álvaro González ; this seems to solve my problem.

Comment: For MySQL 5.7+ I recommend using [`sys.list_add(@@SESSION.sql_mode, 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES')`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-list-add.html)

Comment: I also had to remove NO_ZERO_DATE and STRICT_TRANS_TABLES froim @@SESSION.sql_mode.

Answer (score 1):

September have only 30 days. So your queries must be as follows -

**Query 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM db1.table1
WHERE date_column >= '2019-09-01 00:00:00' AND date_column <= '2019-09-30 23:59:59';
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM db1.table1
WHERE date_column BETWEEN '2019-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-09-30 23:59:59' ;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Bajpai, but I want resolution for invalid dates only .

Comment: 9-31 is invalid date actually.

Comment: Mentioning again :- As we're migrating from MySQL 5 to MySQL 8, fixing the invalid date queries would require a lot of effort in code change. Hence I'm looking for a solution which requires least changes like changes in configuration only.